# Negative votes on meta should not be migrated as well

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, migration

Do negative votes on questions that were incorrectly posted in meta and then being migrated to the main site, like [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10732/systems-of-linear-equations) (the main question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473840/solve-systems-of-linear-equations)), carry over their reputation malus for the main user?

This shouldn't be since negative votes work different on meta. I flagged the question. Is flagging the right way for other such cases?

Comment: Huh. I figured that this was the case. We did fiddle summat with migrations and votes a while back but I don't recall this being an intended consequence, so I'll bring it up.

Comment: Is this really the same question, though? To me it looks like the meta version is closed rather than migrated, and the main version was posted independently of it. They just happen to have the same number of downvotes at the moment. (cc: @GraceNote)

Comment: @user could be... but i remember that a high rep user( maybe ross millikan) who posted an answer that showed up on meta and on main

Comment: @user You seem to be correct. The deleted post on Meta was deleted, not migrated, nor is there any migration history. There is even a comment on the meta post indicating that a copy already existed on the main site.

Comment: @user is Angelas comment identical? I'm using my tablet right now and it's a p.i.t.a. Here...can u check text and timestamp?

Comment: I did not read the comments, and now it's too late: the meta version is gone. But the point is: when a question is migrated, it is automatically *deleted*, and its URL redirects. When you actually see a question in two places, this is not the result of migration.

Comment: @user i was confused by rob's comment and the on_hold-status. I still wonder if ross put his answer then on both sides or my memory is wrong about that...

Comment: There was never an answer on the original question on Meta, according to the post history that I can review.

Comment: @GraceNote then i was wrong and the case can be closed. Hasta luego...

Comment: @user: [your comment is false](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10738/negative-votes-on-meta-should-not-be-migrated-as-well?noredirect=1#comment40511_10738) migrated questions only gets deleted after a certain amount of time (1 month or something like that) has passed. Not immediately. See, for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/474236/1543 vs http://mathoverflow.net/q/140195/3948 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/470017/1543 vs http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/208538

Comment: As Grace indicates: the question was deleted by one user + one mod, the mod having cast his deletion vote after he was notified that duplicate version has already been posted on main, so that migration is not needed.

Comment: @WillieWong From the viewpoint of a user, the migrated question no longer exists on the originating site; only a stub with "migrated" is visible, not the question itself. Clicking the title (or following the URL) redirects to the target site.

Comment: @GraceNote I do suggest looking carefully at the handling of votes on migrated questions.  When Arduino.SE closed down and migrated most of its questions to EE.SE, I found that I could end up voting twice for the same question/answer (once before it was migrated/while still on Arduino.SE, and once after it was migrated to the new site)  This is probably a whole different problem, though, and deserves a separate thread...

Comment: @anorton: that is [status by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)